# How to get command id for keybinding

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run a command 'Emmet:Go to Matching Pair' with keybinding 'ctrl+m'

'Emmet:Go to matching pair' is exactly what I see on ctrl+shift+P

Here keybind in keybindings.json:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "Emmet: Go to Matching Pair",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Error:

> command 'Emmet: Go to Matching Pair' not found

How to get the proper id of the command?

Comment: There's an extra space, was that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. However, instead of entering the command name one has to enter the *command ID*. You get the command ID in the *Keyboard Shortcuts* view (opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>). Now when you search for your command *Emmet: Go to Matching Pair* and hover over it the corresponding command ID is shown.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Therefore you have to use `editor.emmet.action.matchTag` instead. So the following will do:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.matchTag",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: Right-click on the command label for an option to copy the actual command ID.